# Google Protobuf - Java - Issue in 'import' of proto files in one another

Tags: java, maven

I've created a sample maven project in java and having the below configuration:

- I am using below maven-antrun-plugin in my **pom.xml** :

```
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                   <execution>
                      <id>generate-sources</id>
                      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                      <configuration>
                         <target>
                            <echo>Generate</echo>
                            <path id="proto.path">
                               <fileset dir="src/main/java/com/xyz/zrtb/simulator/proto">
                                  <include name="**/*.proto" />
                               </fileset>
                            </path>
                            <pathconvert pathsep=" " property="proto.files" refid="proto.path" />
                            <exec executable="protoc" failonerror="true">
                               <arg value="--java_out=src/main/java" />
                               <arg value="--proto_path=${project.basedir}/src/main/java/com/xyz/zrtb/simulator/proto/" />
                               <arg line="${proto.files}" />
                            </exec>
                         </target>
                         <sourceRoot>src/</sourceRoot>
                      </configuration>
                      <goals>
                         <goal>run</goal>
                      </goals>
                   </execution>
                </executions>
             </plugin>
          </plugins>
```

**Note:** Above configuration works fine with the plain proto files where I am not having any 'import' statements or 'objects as variables' in my message However It does not work with the file having 'import' statements or 'objects as variables'.

Below are the proto files I am using:

**a.proto** :

```
option java_package = "com.xyz.zrtb.simulator.protos";
option java_outer_classname = "A";

message a {
    optional string id = 1;
    optional string name = 2;
    repeated string cat = 4;
    optional string domain = 3;
}
```

**b.proto** :

```
option java_package = "com.xyz.zrtb.simulator.protos";
option java_outer_classname = "b";

import "a.proto";

message b {
    optional string id = 1;
    optional string name = 2;
    optional string domain = 3;
    repeated string cat = 4;
    optional string page = 5;
    optional string ref = 6;
    optional A a = 7;
}
```

These proto files are in the same package named as **com.xyz.zrtb.simulator.proto**

Below is the project structure:

```
     MyProject
       |------src/main/java (source folder)
                          |------ com.xyz.zrtb.simulator.proto
                          |------ com.xyz.zrtb.simulator.protos (for generated java files)
```

Above all explains the structure, the error which I am getting while running maven **generate-sources** is given below:

```
    [INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (generate-sources) @ myproject-web ---
    [INFO] Executing tasks

    main:
         [echo] Generate
         [exec] site.proto:13:14: "A" is not defined.
```

I tried lot of options however did not get this work, please help. It could be a '--proto-path' problem. I've tried the below import statements but it didn't work:

- import "com/xyz/zrtb/simulator/proto/a.proto"
- import "src/main/java/com/xyz/zrtb/simulator/proto/a.proto"
- import "MyProject/src/main/java/com/xyz/zrtb/simulator/proto/a.proto"

Comment: This is solved. Solution can be found (http://executeitwithease.blogspot.in/2014/10/google-protobuf-get-it-working-in-linux.html)

Comment: Please write an answer.